# What is the fundamental difference between flags and kwargs with bool values in Python?

Tags: python

e. g. [flags are used in module `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#flags).

When do I need to use flags when writing my own module, and when do I need keywords with bool values? Is it just a matter of convenience or not?

```py
def foo1 (bar, flags=0):
    ...

def foo2 (bar, flag=False):
    ...

foo1 (bar, FLAG)
foo2 (bar, flag=True)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "flags" it appears that you mean [`enum.Flag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag) or [`enum.IntFlag`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag) (the flags used by the `re` module you have linked to are derived from `IntFlag`).

A `bool` can encode *one* yes/no decision in one object.

An `[Int]Flag` can encode *multiple* yes/no decisions in one object.

Comment: I think the question is comparing an `IntFlag` to several named Boolean arguments (which can be splatted in with `**kwargs`)

Comment: Yes, and you would need multiple bools to replace one IntFlag.